# Swift 4 alternative if let

Tags: swift, option-type

I have this code, it checks if a file exists in the document directory, if it does it used this to set up the data for the controller, if it doesn't it uses a file supplier in the bundle, and if also that fails it set up an empty view controller.

Is there a way to conditionally set the `url` variable so that I can write the `parse(fromFile:)` method once instead of in an if else? The most intuitive way would appear to be `if let url = something || let url = somethingElse` then perform in the `parse(fromFile: url)` in the brackets, but it appears that it's not possible with swift.

```
if let url = try? FileManager().url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                    in: .userDomainMask,
                                    appropriateFor: nil,
                                    create: true).appendingPathComponent("database.json") {
    parse(fromFile: url)
} else if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "database", withExtension: "json") {
    parse(fromFile: url)
} else {
    setUpWithNothing()
}
```

Comment: In this case I wouldn't be really worried about using `try!`. Can the `try? FileManager().url(...)` even fail? The document directory should always exist. Also, you should use `FileManager.default` instead of creating a new one using `FileManager()`. I don't think that the code actually checks that the file exists. At least I don't see anything in the documentation that would suggest so.

Comment: @Sulthan, I didn't think the existence would be checked either but running the code without a database.json in the Documents directory actually uses the database.json supplied in the Bundle, so who knows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to split the code into several steps:

```
let documentsUrl = try! FileManager.default.url(
    for: .documentDirectory,
    in: .userDomainMask,
    appropriateFor: nil,
    create: true
)
```

The documents directory should always exists therefore I am not too worried about using `try!`. However, if you worry, you should solve that special case separately, e.g. using:

```
 guard let documentUrl = try? ... else {
     setUpWithNothing()
     return
 }
```

Then:

```
let fileUrl = documentUrl.appendingPathComponent("database.json")
```

This call never fails, it doesn't check the existence of the file. You need to check existence explicitly:

```
let fileExists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileUrl.path)

let defaultUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "database", withExtension: "json")
let databaseUrl = fileExists ? fileUrl : defaultUrl!
```

Again, you shouldn't worry about the existence of the file in your bundle, if you know it's there and simply call:

```
parse(fromFile: databaseUrl)
```

However, if you want to be extra careful, just remove the `!` and use:

```
if let databaseUrl = fileExists ? fileUrl : defaultUrl {
    parse(fromFile: databaseUrl)
} else {
    setUpWithNothing()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [nil-coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72):

If the expression with FileManager returns nil (by throwing, thanks to the `try?`), then `Bundle.main.url(...)` will be used instead.

If that is also nil, then the conditional binding will fail entirely, and the else block will be run `setUpWithNothing()`.

```
if let url = (try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                           in: .userDomainMask,
                                           appropriateFor: nil,
                                           create: true
                                           ).appendingPathComponent("database.json"))
             ?? Bundle.main.url(forResource: "database", withExtension: "json") {
    parse(fromFile: url)
} else {
    setUpWithNothing()
}
```

Comment: It tells me that `Value of optional type 'URL?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?` in the `parse(fromFile: url)` method call.

Comment: @FrancescoZaffaroni You need to put parentheses around the `try?` expression for that to work. I've edited the answer, and it should compile now.

Comment: @Alexander only appending the pathComponent to the documentDirectory url doesn't mean the file exists at that URL. Btw it will always succeed in iOS

Comment: Resuming `setUpWithNothing()` will never be executed and `parse(fromFile: url)` will always try to parse the file at the documents directory even if the file doesn't exists at that path

Comment: I would select this as te correct answer since it's reusable also for other `if let var = something ?? somethingElse` but as other users pointed out it's not going to work in my specific use case due to the first expression not checking for the existence of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're doing the same thing in the first two cases and something different in the second, this is a good candidate for it's own function:

```
func databaseFileURL() -> URL? {
    if let url = try? FileManager().url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask,
                                        appropriateFor: nil, create: true) {
        return url.appendingPathComponent("database.json")
    } 
    else { 
        return Bundle.main.url(forResource: "database", withExtension: "json")
    }
}
```

and then you can just do

```
if let url = databaseFileURL() {
    parse(fromFile: url)
} else {
    setUpWithNothing()
}
```

It nicely separates concerns and makes it cleaner and clearer at the point of use. And if you need to do anything else with the file you can just call the function rather than copy-pasting the logic.